# Is there a workaround for Windows 10 invisible frame border in java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, windows-10

I've discovered an issue with Windows 10 and Java.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

When I create a new JFrame and show it on the screen, it normally should have the screen coordinates x=0 and y=0. It actually does have those coordinates on windows 10.

But, what is really ugly, is, that it seems all windows in Windows 10 have some kind of "invisible" borders around them. So in this case it looks like the position of the Window is x=7 and y=0:

[image: Invisible window border causes an optically space to neighbor elements]

This is only a simple case where it just looks so ugly. My software has some logic which will "snap" one window onto another when you drag it in the near of the other one. I think you can imagine how ugly it looks if theres a (2*7px=) 14px space between the two windows altough it should be shown for the user as "linked" or "snapped" together.

[image: Expecatation of "snapped" windows and reality]

On Windows 7 this has worked perfectly!

So does somebody know this problem and have any idea, how a workaround could be possible? I think of maybe finding out the current name of the windows theme and operating system name. And if it is "Aero" and "Windows 10", always just calculate x positions with -7px. Would that be somehow possible? Or maybe directly finding out what is the width of the invisible area?

Thanks for any idea about this topic.

Comment: You can get the width of that transparent border from the JFrame’s `getInsets()` method, but I don’t know how to detect whether that border is actually transparent.

Comment: Left inset is 8px. But this value includes the width of the visible frame. So if I set the position of a JFrame to "new Point(-8,0)", the 1px visible border is also off screen.

Comment: It's quite wierd

Comment: It’s not invisible. It’s a semi-transparent shadow.

Answer (score 2):

This could solve your problem :

```
public static void setJFrameBounds(JFrame frame, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    Insets insets = ((Window)frame).getInsets();
    frame.setBounds(x - insets.left, y, width, height);
}
```

Edit : the JFrame must be visible before calling the function